# How to delete TOP n results in SQL 2000?

Tags: sql-server-2000

I know in SQL Server 2005 we could do something like:

> DELETE TOP 10 FROM tbX where X = 1

What could be the query to do the same in SQL2K, **considering** that the primary key is composed by two FK columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

hacky, but:

```
SET ROWCOUNT 10
DELETE FROM tbX where X = 1
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

I wouldn't write this myself, though ;-p

(I'm off to wash my hands...)

Comment: my previous job had this reporting framework and they had the brilliant idea to restrict all reports to 50,000 rows using set rowcount, needless to say, reports that returned only 100 rows could end up having the wrong results if they needed to churn through to much data.

Comment: Yes - very dangerous if you don't limit it to very tightly scoped and understood operations. Actually, I could just stop at "very dangerous".

Comment: I did this, very hacky, but useful in my case, since I have SQL2K ;)

Comment: Hacky but works. Useful if you need to get rid of full duplicates where you can't really discriminate in your WHERE clause.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in SQL2012:

```
;with window as (select top (12) * from PromoterQueue order by LogId)
delete from window
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE
FROM tbX
WHERE id IN (SELECT TOP 10 id FROM tbX WHERE X = 1)
```

You would have to delete the foreign key records first.

Comment: I don't have an 'id'. Primary key is composed by two FK columns.

Answer (score 0):

when dealing with a composite key I would delete like this.

```
delete from tblX
from tblx as aa
join
(
  select top 10 * from tblX
) as bb
on
  aa.key1 = bb.key1
  and
  aa.key2 = bb.key2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not working SQL but something along the lines may work:

```
DELETE t
from tbx t 
join (
  select top 10 k1,k2 from tbx
) as t2 on t.k1 = t2.k1 and t.k2 = t2.k2
```

Note: If TOP does not work in the subquery just insert the stuff into a temp table and join.